# How to add image options: cropping, resizing, etc. to http image file

Tags: html, image, http, resize

I would like to know how do I add image options the image size on request. I have seen something like:

```
                        http://exampleimage.png?w=120&h=200
```

Sometimes they even add options to crop, zoom, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear, in order to resize, crop, etc. an image you need to manipulate it by using other technologies, like html5, css, js, php, c#, java, c++, you name it. It is not enough to add parameters to the url to accomplish it. Please add more details. I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Alright thanks for the response. Basically I want to reference the image using http. For example: <img src="http://example.png"> . But then I want to manipulate the image file (http://example.png) before it comes. I want to find a way to pass the parameters so that the image that comes back is the size that I want. So I have seen something like http://exampleimage.png?w=120&h=200 whereby w is the width in pixels, and h is the height. In this case, the image gets resized without js, php etc.